# Run Shell script on boot in AOSP 11

Tags: android, security, android-source, init, selinux

I am building AOSP 11 for emulator x86_64 and trying to run shell script on boot.

Below is my shell script test.sh

```
#!/vendor/bin/sh

echo "Hello" >> /data/local/tmp/test.txt
```

created myrc.rc file to create service

```
service runapp /vendor/bin/test.sh
        class main
        seclabel u:r:init-myservice:s0
        user root
        group root
        oneshot
        disabled

on property:dev.bootcomplete=1
        start runapp
```

In device/generic/goldfish/sepolicy/x86/file_contexts i have file_contexts with

```
/vendor/bin/test.sh u:object_r:init-myservice_exec:s0
```

In device/generic/goldfish/sepolicy/x86/init-myservice.te

```
type init-myservice, domain;
type init-myservice_exec, exec_type, vendor_file_type, file_type;

init_daemon_domain(init-myservice)

allow init-myservice vendor_file_type:file { execute getattr map open read };
allow init-myservice vendor_toolbox_exec:file read;
```

Add myrc.rc and test.sh in device/generic/goldfish/x86_64-vendor.mk file

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
    external/service/test.sh:$(TARGET_COPY_OUT_VENDOR)/bin/test.sh \
    external/service/myrc.rc:$(TARGET_COPY_OUT_VENDOR)/etc/init/myrc.rc \
```

In build/make/target/board/generic_x86_64/BoardConfig.mk

```
BOARD_SEPOLICY_DIRS += device/generic/goldfish/sepolicy/x86
```

But I can't see any file test.txt created in /data/local/tmp/

It's look like service not running on boot.

I have checked dmesg logs but there not any logs of "runapp" service which i have
created.

Anyone have idea on this ?

Comment: I am aslo facing same problem, May i know issue is resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

@GNK, for the rooted device below solution, is working
No need to define any domain.

create rc file with the below configuration

```
service runapp /system/bin/test.sh
         class main
         seclabel u:r:su:s0
         user root
         group root
         oneshot
         disabled
 
 on property:dev.bootcomplete=1
         start runapp
```

Modify your make file to put these files.

1. `Put rc file in /etc/init/`
2. `Put test.sh in /system/bin/`

Comment: Thank for your reply. I am using Android12 rooted device. Service not stated in boot up time & not getting any related logs. Do we need to do any more

Comment: @GNK There can be a possibility that your device is booting up in enforce mode

Comment: what could be the solution for this, do you have any idea?

Comment: my device is in Permissive mode

Comment: @GNK No idea for this